# Stuck at welcome logo whenever I try to start

Tags: boot, dual-boot, startup, black-screen

I am beginner and last time I didn't make any configuration or change
When I got stuck I just force shutdown my laptop and I could've never start anything
[image: start logo]

Comment: in order to fix the problem you have to diagnose where it comes from. What I can suggest is to press the **Esc** key and edit your question with the ERRORS you see in the screen when you switch from logo to text by pressing the above mentioned key.

Comment: Adding to what Borislav said, you can press e on the grub menu (where you choose to boot ubuntu or other OS) and write `nomodeset` between `quiet splash`, like `quiet nomodeset splash`. Then continue booting with F10.